# AWS SimpleDB js API call

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have an node server app. that lists items in an AWS Simple Db using a node plugin aws2 for authorisation;

```
var aws2  = require('aws2');

var opts = {service: 'sdb', 
            path: '/?Action=ListDomains&Version=2009-04-15&MaxNumberOfDomains=2&NextToken=', 
            region: 'eu-west-1'}

aws2.sign(opts, {
          secretAccessKey: "<secrtet-key>",
          accessKeyId: "<access-key-id>"})
```

and then;

```
http.request(opts, function(request) 
{ 
    request.pipe(process.stdout); 
    // res.send(process.stdout);
}).end()
```

which works fine;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListDomainsResponse xmlns="http://sdb.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-04-15/">
    <ListDomainsResult>
      <DomainName>db1</DomainName>
      <DomainName>db2</DomainName>
       </ListDomainsResult>
      <ResponseMetadata>
  <RequestId>46df0bd2-2ed8-de4b-5df8-ad602eda72c9</RequestId>
  <BoxUsage>0.0000071759</BoxUsage>
   </ResponseMetadata>
</ListDomainsResponse>
```

The problem I'm having is one I solved in an earlier post regarding having the request pause till the XML is returned.

I solved the issue previously with the node request package;

```
request(url, function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

        parseString(body, function (err, result) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        });

        // from within the callback, write data to response, essentially returning it.
        res.send(body);
    }
    else {
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
})
```

The bit I'm struggling with is getting http.request to behave in a similar manner to request.

Is this possible? I have tried constructing the url from the opts object and passing it to request but I keep getting "request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided"

Could someone advise me on what I need to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution;

```
var opts = {
    service: 'sdb',
    path: '/?Action=ListDomains&Version=2009-04-15&MaxNumberOfDomains=2&NextToken=',
    region: this.accessData.region
}

//read this in from a file (encrypted?)
aws2.sign(opts, {
    secretAccessKey: this.accessData.secretAccessKey,
    accessKeyId: this.accessData.accessKeyId
})

var req = http.request(opts, function (resp) {

    resp.setEncoding('utf8');
    resp.on('data', function (chunk) {
        if (debug) { console.log('domains : ' + chunk) };

        listDomainMetaData('name', function (metad) {
            if (debug) { console.log("metad: " + metad) };

            res.send(chunk + metad);

        });            

    });
});

req.on('error', function (e) {
    if (debug) { console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message) };
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```